# Vue put focus on an input via refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, focus, ref

I use v-for to create inputs foreach item in a list, i assign a ref in the following way

```
:ref="`input-${index}`"
```

which makes my $refs look like this

[image]

Now my question is; on the addition of an input I also want to put focus on the last input, however I can't manage to make it work.

Right now I tried something like this,

```
this.$refs["input-" + index.toString()].focus()
```

however I feel like it has to do with the structure of refs I don't know how to deal with.

Does anybody know how I can access each input and how to focus it (i guess just .focus()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I do not know exactly anymore, however I remember that the problem was that I was putting focus on the ion-item rather than the ion-input. I needed to add .children[i] (i depending on what child it is). this allowed me to put focus in the input :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using ref inside a v-for loop, in this case is recommended to use the ref in the root element containing the `v-for` directive as follows :

```
 <input v-for="(item, index) in items" ref="inputs" .../>
```

this will create an array of the referenced elements that you could use them like :

```
 this.$refs.inputs[someIndex].focus()
```

or

```
 this.$refs.inputs[this.$refs.inputs.length-1].focus() // focus on the last input
```

Comment: Hey @Boussadjra

Comment: @Amaarrockz hello my friend

Comment: I tried this and I still get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')". I don't know the importance of this, but I have more inside the v-for besides just an input

Comment: where do you call that focus function and how do you define the ref

Comment: I put ref="inputs" on the element with v-for and I call focus like this:
this.$refs.inputs[this.inputs.length - 1].focus(). I call it after pushing an empty string to the inputs array which results in a new input element. To me it seems like this is exactly how you meant it. However what I think might be a problem is that the element with v-for contains multiple elements (an ion-label, ion-input and ion-icon)

Comment: I tested that if the index turned out good, this did not seem like the problem, however when i just enter for index a literal 0 i do get the actual items inside the v-for. Now I just have the same issue as i thought of, that the v-for contains multiple elements

Comment: Edit: I managed to access the input by doing .children[1].children[0], and the focussing of an input by .focus() does not work on an ion-input. Instead I had to use .setFocus() -_-. Only problem left is that I can only focus on all the inputs except the last one (the one I want).